# How to return CHAR30 in AMDP?

Tags: abap, hana-sql-script, amdp

I try to create an AMDP method that returns a single field that would be SNWD_COMPANY_NAME on the ABAP side. The documentation says only *table types* and *elementary types* can be returned.

SNWD_COMPANY_NAME is not elementary, it is CHAR 80, but I don't want to return the whole 19 field of SNWD_BPA, and the elementary type `C` has a length of only 1.

How can I return a single row, single field of a table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please check following AMDP code?

```
class zcl_kodyaz_amdp_test definition

  public
  final
  create public .

  public section.

  INTERFACES if_amdp_marker_hdb.

class-methods read_company_name
    importing value(node_key) type SNWD_NODE_KEY
    exporting value(company_name) type SNWD_COMPANY_NAME
      raising   cx_amdp_error.

  protected section.
  private section.
endclass.

class zcl_ey_amdp_test implementation.

  method read_company_name
    by database procedure
    for hdb language sqlscript
    options read-only
    using SNWD_BPA.

select COMPANY_NAME into "COMPANY_NAME" from SNWD_BPA where NODE_KEY = :node_key;

  endmethod.

endclass.
```